# Automatically order videos

Tags: video

I'm looking a program or web service/application that can take an input a collection of videos, and output the most likely order of the videos.

My use case: I have 5 video cut into 10 video files each (=50 video files in total). I'd like a program that give me the most likely order of the videos.

Any OS, any license, any price is fine. CLI or GUI.